# Running wireguard VPN and noip2. How do I update my DDNS to my default public IP with namespace?

Tags: linux, vpn, systemd, noip

I'm running wireguard VPN on my linux machine (B) as a client connecting to a server (A) in a different country.
I also need to access B remotely without using the VPN so I'm running a noip2 DUC DDNS to update my public IP with systemd.
(B) has 4 eth ports and is setup as a bridge with eth1-3 going to eth0.
But noip2 only gets the public IP of (A).

I want to create a namespace so that noip2 will update my DDNS with the public IP of (B)
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NS="nsx"
IF_MAIN="br0"
IF_NS="br0_ns"
IP="192.168.10.2/24"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.1"

ip netns del "$NS"
ip netns add "$NS"
ip link add link "$IF_MAIN" "$IF_NS" netns "$NS" type ipvlan mode l2
ip -n "$NS" link set dev lo up
ip -n "$NS" link set "$IF_NS" up
ip -n "$NS" addr add "$IP" dev "$IF_NS"
ip -n "$NS" route add default via "$GATEWAY" dev "$IF_NS"
```

But the last line returns `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.`

Any ideas on how to run noip2 DUC on systemd on a different namespace?

Comment: Typo? 192.168.10.2/24 -> 192.168.1.2/24?